# this.props.params not existing after passing parameter on react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm passing parameter from react-router's route path to component but in this.props object, 'params' not existing

```
const routes = (
    <Router forceRefresh={true}>
        <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Firstpage}/>
            <Route exact path="/projects" component={Projectslist}/>
            <Route exact path="/projects/:projectId" component={Singleproject}/>
        </div>
    </Router>
);
```

And this is my component:

```
class Singleproject extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        window.document.title = "Wploper | Project title";
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Mainheader/>
                <div id="single-project-container" className="sheet-max-width">
                    <h2>{this.props.params}</h2>
                </div>
                <Mainfooter/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And the object (this.props) hasn't params:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TL5xV.png)

Comment: Which react-router version are you using?

Comment: Also paste the code from where you are calling the route which receives the param.

Comment: It is 4th version.

Comment: I'm testing it with console.log in constructor

Answer (score 6):

tested for react-router v4
in your Singleproject component you can get the params by :

```
this.props.match.params.projectId
```

below is a code sample :

```
    class ForgotPassword extends Component {
        constructor (props,context){
            super(props,context);
            this.state={
                busy : true,
                sessionId : localStorage.getItem('sessionId') || null,
                resetKey : this.props.match.params.resetKey || ''
            };
            console.log(this);
        }
}
```

Comment: Works for me! Thank you. Strange that I find it so long time.

Answer (score 0):

In react-router version 4 you can get the path params with `this.props.match.params`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the parameter from the route through **context**.
`this.context.params.projectId`